# Creating some sort of macro in adobe/bracket

Tags: macros, adobe-brackets

I am new to using adobe/brackets and I've been wondering since I've come from being a sublime text user, is there any method for basically chaining commands like macro in adobe/brackets?

I know how to override shortcuts in keymap.json but I still do not know how to create macro-like function. Do I need to write it by myself like in atom editor? If it is, where should I put it and how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Brackets doesn't have a special macro language, but Brackets itself is written in JavaScript so it's very easy to write extensions to do whatever custom actions you want. (Another way to look at it is: Brackets lets you write macros in JavaScript).

[Here's how to get started](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Write-Extensions), and here's a [simple example extension](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Simple-%22Hello-World%22-extension).